# App Stores, Size limits and more

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

Ive googled for hours trying to find the answer, im sure its out there but i cant find it...  I have an app that works fine on google play using google services etc.  It uses the expansion obb files to download the majority of the game files.  I also use achievements from the google services and IAP.

I need to also distribute via some of the other app stores.  While I can find information about IAP using samsung and amazon, what about expansion obb systems and achievements/cloud saves/leaderboards etc.

I appreciate that most devices have google play etc on them, but my understanding is i should be able to run without them so with that in mind

1. Do I need to host the expansion files myself and download them from my own servers if running from a samsung store/amazon store download etc. (The obb size is nearly 600mb)
2. The IAP is fine with other stores, i presume i just have a different apk for those stores with the relevant IAP handling code.
3. Do they support the google services stuff like achievements, should the game handle that not being available on samsung stores etc (and maybe even if downloade from the google store?)

Many Thanks

Comment: you can accept the answer if you feel its worth it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its a Good Question,

If you have your app in Google Play and planning to release app on other stores like AMAZON,SAMSUNG the you should have seperate accounts and upload apk files in those stores.

1) Regarding OBB files or expansion files its only in Google Store, Amazon and samsung does not have limit of 50 MB, so if your apk is more than 50mb also your can just upload your apk file.

2) Regarding the In App Billing - amazon and samsung have there own APIs and we need to implement that for IAP to work on those store and these APIs are given in there offical websites and they have even given a sample app to test.

3) Regarding the Game Center - amazon gives us the game center api and we need to implement that inorder for the apps to work.

I hope i have cleared all your points.

```
Links : 

1) Amazon IAP - https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/in-app-purchasing.html

2) Samusng IAP - http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/In-App-Purchase-Library

3) Amazon Game Circle - https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/gamecircle.html
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: One complementary note would be, regarding point (3) that, Google play services and all functionality related to them (Maps, GCM, IAP, Game Services, etc) is only available to Google Play enabled devices. This means that for other devices e.g. Amazon Kindle you should take care for using their solutions. Regarding IAP, have a look at [OpenIAB](https://github.com/onepf/OpenIAB) it looks promising, though still under heavy development.

Comment: Yes, i did wonder whether to just make the apk larger and store the files in the raw folder but i read alot of people having issues with samsung store if there apps are over 30mb?  I also noticed alot of games still have a small apk with a download on first run.

Gotta love the fun of handling multiple apk/multiple stores ;)  I wish there was a command line system for submitting apk to each store so it could be automated.

Comment: I found this..
'Just small warning:
 Official Android Market limit is 50 MB, but there is ~30 MB limit
 on Samsung devices due to download cache size.'  I appreciate this is old because android market limit has the 4gb limit now with expansion files but i couldnt find anything to suggest samsung had altered their limits

Comment: Ive updated the question, the apk would be in the region of 600mb if its bundled together.... Not sure if that makes a difference

Comment: @AdrianBrown if your apk file is 50+MB for google play use OBB, for amazon will use FTP - details on official webstie, samsung store no issue

Comment: @Bororo i agree with you

Comment: @Goofy - so the issues with 30+mb on samsung isnt an issue any more.  Amazon say that ideally you wouldnt use an apk > 100mb but you can use the ftp if you need to, i guess ill see what happens when a 600mbish apk lands on it :D